# Django perform a join on multiple tables

Tags: python, django, orm

I have the following tables:

```
class A: 
    field_1 = models.CharField()
    field_2 = models.IntegerField()

class B: 
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='table_b')
    some_other_field = models.CharField()

class C: 
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="table_c")
    other_field = models.CharField()
```

Let's assume `ids` are provided for objects on table `A`, I need to get all the `C` objects that are related to table `A` through table `B`. I have the following query, which gives me what I need but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, I was reading into `prefetch_related` and `select_related` but can't wrap my head around on how to use them so far:

```
c_list = C.objects.filter(b__in=B.objects.filter(a__pk__in=table_a_ids))
```

Also, I would like to group them by `other_field`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `.select_related(…)` or `.prefetch_related(…)`. You can filter with:

```
c_list = C.objects.filter(b__a_id__in=table_a_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I need to read more about `select_related` and `prefetch_related`. Will prefetch_related makes sense if I would one to get all the `B` and `C` objects that have a relationship with A